# How can I get a JS Object in Native (Objective-C) for WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to call Javascript function on a JS object from Native in WKUserContentController but there isn't seems to be a possible approach.

My Javascript code (Here, my js-plugin is trying to make a function call to native. Once, native workflow is completed, it should be able to update it-self in nativeWorkflowDone ) :-

```
define(["core/plugin-core"],
       function (PluginCore) {
    "use strict";
    var UPLOAD_LINK= PluginCore.UploadLink.prototype.UPLOAD_STATES;
    _proxy: = {};
    PluginCore.NativeObject= PluginCore.Api.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            PluginCore.Api.prototype.initialize.call(this);

            this.startWorkflow();
        },

        nativeWorkflowDone : function(populatedData) {
                for(var key in populatedData)
                        this._proxy[key] = populatedData[key];
                //HTML to be modified here once nativeWorkflow is done.
        },

        startWorkflow: function(workflowOptions){
                var message = {"object" : this, "function" : nativeWorkflowDone };
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.Workflow.postMessage(message)
        }
};
```

My Objective-C code for handling JS calls :-

```
-(void) userContentController:(nonnull WKUserContentController*)userContentController didRecieveScriptMessage:(nonnull WKScriptMessage*)message{
       if([message.name isEqualToString:@"getCount"]) {
                       NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UpdateCount('%@');", mCount++];
                       [mWebBrowser evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:nil];
       } else if(message.name isEqualToString:@"Workflow"]) {
                      //NOT SURE HOW TO GET JS OBJECT "this" HERE. ALSO, HOW CAN I CALL BACK ON IT Eg this.nativeWorkflowDone ?????.
       }
}
```

Could anyone help me understand how can I get a JS object (such as 'this') in Native WKUserContentController in WKWebView ? Also, how can I call its method from Native ?

Comment: `WKWebView` in contrary to legacy `WebView` does not support Objective-C <> Javascript bridge anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi . Is there a way to achieve same objective in other language such as swift ?

Comment: It is not a matter of language - there is no such feature in WKWebView. All we have now is "evaluate JavaScript" from native app code or "postMessage" from JavaScript.

Comment: Ah !! it's a bummer .. Thanks @Asperi . I was hoping that I would find some API that provide such functionality. WKWebView should provide something like that. It would make itself more useful.